# Can console and PC players play together online?

Tags: fifa-15

I have a gaming PC and plan to buy FIFA 15. My friends already play it on their XBoxes. Is it possible that I join them or does the PC version have its own multiplayer servers?

The only thing I found out about it was that for **former** versions of FIFA it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

No. This is not supported. Each platform is separate.

Answer (score 0):

++ to TZHX for his answer :)

The only thing you *can somehow* do on PC while your actually playing the game on another platform is access your FUT on the web @ https://www.easports.com/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app