# FIFA 2015 cross-generation multiplayer on Playstation 3 and 4

Tags: ps3, ps4, fifa-15

Is it possible to have an online multiplayer match in FIFA 2015 where one player is using a Playstation 3 and the other using a Playstation 4?

Comment: Roughly similar: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185619/can-console-and-pc-players-play-together-online.  The answer should answer your question, though.

Comment: @Frank Cross-gen and Cross-Platform are two different things though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

EA has a negative stance against [cross-platform gaming.](http://www.egmnow.com/articles/news/ea-cant-see-cross-platform-play-coming-to-fifa/), as well as it being reinforced [here](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-Plus-Support/Playing-PS4-games-with-PS3-players-online/td-p/44558510) and [here](https://www.facebook.com/easportsfifa/posts/10152655003959288) from users who have FIFA15.

Also, EA confirms this is not possible on their [message boards](http://answers.ea.com/t5/FIFA-15/Can-ps3-players-play-online-with-ps4-players-on-fifa-15/td-p/3650227).

However, the [technology is there](http://www.polygon.com/2013/10/30/5047272/sony-ps3-and-ps4-cross-play-is-technically-possible) to play cross-gen, companies are just not utilizing it.